# When web crawling how do I find patterns of low quality urls and crawl these type of urls less?

Tags: url, web-crawler

Urls like `exmpl.com/search.php?q=hey` come in huge varieties of GET parameters and I want to classify such links to keep my crawler from crawling such "low priority" urls.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're crawling and what you want to do with it, if it's a few specific websites or a broad crawl. Sometimes the owners of the websites don't want you to crawl those URL's either because they generate additional traffic (traffic which is useless for both), and they may use the robots.txt file also for that. Give it a look (you should respect it anyway).

These low quality URLs, as you call them, may also happen with:

- e-shops where you continuously add items to the cart and the back office gets messed up with the orders
- blog platforms where you click on comments, replies, likes and so on with a weird result
- crawler traps from calendars or other infinite URLs where only the parameters change but the page is the same
- link farms, especially classified ads websites where each product or region is generated as a subdomain and you end up having thousands of subdomains for the same website; even if you have a limited number of URLs downloaded per website, this order of magnitude just takes over your crawl

If you have your contact on the user agent they sometimes contact you to stop crawling specific types of URLs, or to tune with you what should be crawled or not and how (as, for instance, the number of requests per second).

So, it depends on what you're trying to crawl. Look at the frontier and try to find weird behaviours:

- hundreds of URLs for the same website where the URL is mostly the same and only one or a few parameters change
- hundreds of URLs for blog platforms or e-shops where the parameters looks weird or keep repeating (look at those platforms and try to find patterns in them like `(.*\?widgetType=.*)` or `(.*\&action=buy_now.*)`)
- URLs that look like being from calendars
- hundreds of URLs that interact with forms that you're not interested in submitting information to (like the search you mentioned)
- a number of URLs for a website that is too high for what you'd expect for that website or a website of that type
- a number of subdomains for a website that is too high
- websites with a high number of 403, 404 or 500 or non-200 codes and which URLs are responsible for that
- a frontier that doesn't stop growing and which websites and URLs are responsible for that (which URLs are being added so much that make it grow weirdly)

All those URLs are good candidates to be excluded from the crawl. Identify the common part and use it as a regular expression in the exclusion rules.